# The socle of an almost simple group

Tags: normal-subgroups, simple-groups, automorphism-group, socle

By definition an almost simple group is a group $G$ with
$$T \cong \mathrm{Inn}(T)\trianglelefteq G \leq \mathrm{Aut}(T),$$
where $T$ is a non-abelian simple group. How would one show that in this case the socle of $G$ is equal to $\mathrm{Inn}(T)$?

I have seen one argument in a book which says that from the above we get $C_{G}(\mathrm{Inn}(T))=1$ (the centraliser in $G$ of $\mathrm{Inn}(T)$) and thus $\mathrm{Inn}(T)$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$ from which the result follows. The only part of this argument I fail to understand is how we obtain $C_{G}(\mathrm{Inn}(T))=1$ from the definition.

Comment: What is a "socle"?

Comment: @MarkFischler The socle of $G$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by all its minimal normal subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g\in C_G(\mathrm{Inn}(T))$. Then $g^{-1}\varphi_tg = \varphi_t$ for any $t\in T$. For any $x\in T$, we have
\begin{equation*}
t^{-1}xt = x^{\varphi_t} = x^{g^{-1}}\varphi_tg = (t^{-1}(x^{g^{-1}})t)^g = (t^g)^{-1}xt^g
\end{equation*}
and so $x = t(t^g)^{-1}xt^gt^{-1}$, which implies $t(t^g)^{-1}\in Z(T) = \{1\}$. Therefore, $t = t^g$ for any $t\in T$. So $g$ is trivial in $\mathrm{Aut}(T)$ and in $G$.